# Android FacebookSDK 4.6.0 share fitness.runs with feelings

Tags: android, facebook, share, facebook-opengraph

```
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
    .setActionType(graphPath)
    .putString("fitness:course", courseUrl)
    .putBoolean("fb:explicitly_shared", true)
    .build();

ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
    .setPreviewPropertyName("fitness:course")
    .setAction(action)
    .build();


if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareOpenGraphContent.class)) {
    shareDialog.show(content);
}
```

This code works well to me, but there is no option to add a feeling to it. If I add for example "feeling fantastic" in share dialog, it won't be visible in my final post on the timeline, but my location and a custom message is still visible. What I'm doing wrong?

Is there an option to add a feeling programmatically?

Comment: Not all Facebook story types can have a "feeling" attached to them.

Comment: @derabbink Thanks! But it works with the Runtastic app.

Comment: Generally speaking you can't expect to be able to everything on Facebook Platform that other apps can do. Other apps may have different capabilities. Perhaps you can add a screen shot of the share sheet you see when invoking this code. That will allow others to better understand where things go "wrong" for you.

Comment: @derabbink Okay here we go: I added a screenshot of a facebook share with "feelings" and location attached to it: http://s21.postimg.org/khn039u2v/share.png

Comment: It looks like you censored part of your action. What comes before "gemacht"?
What happens if you click the blue smiley above the letter "e" on your keyboard?